# Velocity - #springFormInput and custom ID

Tags: java, spring, velocity

Whenever I use `#springFormInput` like:

```
#springFormInput("command.name")
```

I get markup with ID set to `name`:

```
<input type="text" id="name" ... />
```

In many cases I want short names like "category" or "name", and I don't feel comfortable with having them in the ID (which is supposed to be unique). How can I instruct Spring to use different ID for the element?

I tried something like:

```
#springFormInput("command.name" 'id="myid" data-zaza="test"')
```

... but my ID is still being overwritten:

```
<input type="text" id="name" data-zaza="test" ... />
```

I would like it to emit `id="myid"` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Take a look at the macro's code:

```sh
#**
 * springFormInput
 *
 * Display a form input field of type 'text' and bind it to an attribute
 * of a command or bean.
 *
 * @param path the name of the field to bind to
 * @param attributes any additional attributes for the element (such as class
 *    or CSS styles or size
 *
 *#
#macro( springFormInput $path $attributes )
    #springBind($path)
    <input type="text" id="${status.expression}" name="${status.expression}"
                            value="$!status.value" ${attributes}#springCloseTag()
#end
```

So, as you can see, using `#springFormInput("command.name" 'id="myid" data-zaza="test"')` actually generates:

```
<input type="text" id="name" id="myid" data-zaza="test" />
```

But velocity wipes out the duplicated ID, leaving only the first (`id="name"`).

This "wiping out" behavior becomes clear when you do a test. For instance, declared by hand:

```
<input type="text" id="testA" id="testB" id="testC" name="myTest" value="test!">
```

What goes in the generated HTML is:

```
<input type="text" id="testA" name="myTest" value="test!">
```

As an alternative then, you can use the macro code explicitly, generating what you need:

```
#springBind("command.name")
<input type="text" id="myid" name="${status.expression}"
                         value="$!status.value" data-zaza="test"#springCloseTag()
```

`${status.expression}` and `$!status.value` are set at the `#springBind` macro, don't worry about them.